# Pandas DataFrame DDL Statement from Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+------------+--------------+
| holiday_dt | holiday_name |
+------------+--------------+
| 2015-01-01 | Ano novo     |
| 2015-02-17 | Carnaval     |
| 2015-04-05 | Páscoa       |
| 2015-04-21 | Tiradentes   |
+------------+--------------+
```

I usually have created this dataframe through a series of other processes, not from scratch.

So, I have to manually type out an example so I can post code, like this:

```
dfHolidays = pd.DataFrame({'holiday_dt': ['2015-01-01', '2015-02-17', '2015-04-05','2015-04-21'],
                          'holiday_name': ['Ano novo','Carnaval','Pascoa','Tiradentes']})
```

Is there a way in pandas to generate the statement, given the data?

Comment: `df.to_json()` ? then combine it with `pd.read_json(s)` ?

Comment: the result of `df.to_dict()` also works for the `pd.DataFrame()`

Comment: This is the best answer so far. I like it. Throw it up as an answer and I can accept it for the benefit of others. Thanks!

Comment: @Josh are you talking about my tip or Joran?

Comment: Maybe both options are pretty good. I liked how the json one worked better, but both are good options. If noone posts it, I'll just answer it myself but I'll wait, since you know, internet points. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = df.to_json()

print('''pandas.read_json("""s""")''')
```

I think would give you roughly what you want

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest thing you can do is: `print(df.to_string())`

You wont get it to look the way you are asking for it, but it will definitely get the point across. E.g.:

```
>>> print(df.to_string())
                 time
0 1990-01-02 09:47:00
1 1990-01-02 09:48:00
2 1990-01-02 09:49:00
3 1990-01-02 09:50:00
4 1990-01-02 09:51:00
5 1990-01-02 09:52:00
6 1990-01-02 09:53:00
7 1990-01-02 09:54:00
8 1990-01-02 09:55:00
```